# Java Minecraft Bukkit promote plugin

Tags: java, minecraft

Here is my code:

```
package meg.zach.d;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("Plugin Enabled");
    }

    public void onDisable() {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String args[]) {
        Player p = (Player) sender;
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("promote") && sender instanceof Player) {
            if (args[0] == "mod") {
                for (Player playerToPromote : Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()) {
                    if (playerToPromote.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(args[1])) {
                        String modN = ChatColor.GRAY + "[Mod] ";
                        playerToPromote.setDisplayName(modN + playerToPromote.getDisplayName());
                        String modb = ChatColor.YELLOW + "has been promoted into a ";
                        String mod = ChatColor.GOLD + "Mod ";
                        Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(playerToPromote + modb + mod);

                    }
                    else if(!(playerToPromote.isOnline())){
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "player not online");
                    }
                }

            }


        }
        return false;
    }
```

So my question is when I do /promote and mod and name it doesn't change the display name or anything, and also `getOnlinePlayers` is deprecated for some reason.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I have rewriten the code to look like this:

```
package meg.zach.d;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    // Got rid of onEnable(), simply sent a message to show the plugin was
    // enabled, but is done automatically by the server

    // Got rid of onDisable(), not necessary if empty

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String args[]) {
        // The below checks if the sender is a player
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            log.info("error message : sender isnt player");
            return true;
        }
        // I can now safely cast sender to type Player
        Player p;
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("commandnamehere")) {
            // Checking if there are enough arguments
            if (args.length != 1) {
                // Message to send when there isn't enough arguments
                p.sendMessage("Look! Not enough arguments!");
                return true;
            }
            if (args[0] == "lookaspecialthingy") {
                // Instead of looping through all the online players, I just try
                // to cast the player name to a Player, and check if the object
                // is null
                Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
                if (target == null) {
                    // Player is offline
                    return true;
                }
                String modN = ChatColor.GRAY + "[Mod] ";
                target.setDisplayName(modN + target.getDisplayName());
                String modb = ChatColor.YELLOW + " has been promoted into a ";
                String mod = ChatColor.GOLD + "Mod!";
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(target + modb + mod);

            }

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this code wasn't tested, but if you change it a bit, it should work just fine.

You would also need to have define the command in your plugin.yml. You can look up how to create a plugin.yml here: http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_YAML

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote it with my had, so I don't know if everything is right, but if it isn't right it is nearly like this! So like `isOfflinePlayer()` could also be `isOnlinePlayer()`...

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String args[]) {
    Player p = (Player) sender;
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("promote") && sender instanceof Player) {
        if (args[0] == "mod") {
            Player playerToPromote = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[1]);
            if (!playerToPromote.isOfflinePlayer()) {
                    String modN = ChatColor.GRAY + "[Mod] ";
                    playerToPromote.setDisplayName(modN + playerToPromote.getDisplayName());
                    String modb = ChatColor.YELLOW + "has been promoted into a ";
                    String mod = ChatColor.GOLD + "Mod ";
                    Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(playerToPromote + modb + mod);
                    playerToPromote.update();
                } else {
                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "player not online");
                }

        }


    }
    return false;
}
```

You have to register your command in the `plugin.yml` and I don't know if the `update()` Method really exist... But with an Inventory it was like this.
Sorry for my bad English and if it still doesn't work just command on my answer ;)